# Using achemso with another bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, achemso

I would like to use the achemso documentclass with another bibliography style (`naturemag`) under overleaf, but it seems to me that it does not work. Could you please help me how to do this? My MWE is as follows:

Bibliography file (`test.bib`):

```
@article{97PoZoTeLo,
author = { O. L. Polyansky and N. F. Zobov and J. Tennyson and J. A. Lotoski and P. F. Bernath},
title = {Hot bands of water in the $\nu_2$ manifold up to $5\nu_2-4\nu_2$},
journal = JMS,
year = {1997},
volume = {184},
pages = {35-50}}
```

Main file (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass[journal=jpclcd,manuscript=letter,articletitle=true,maxauthors=20]{achemso}

    \renewcommand\bibliographystyle{naturemag}

    \title{test}

    \begin{document}

    This is a good article \cite{97PoZoTeLo}.

    \bibliography{test}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The `achemso` class is _purely_ for submission to ACS, so it does not support other styles